# Grid detection using OpenCV

Tags: c#, opencv

Is there an existing function in OpenCV or any other image processing tool which can be used to do a grid view on a chess board video stream? I eventually would want to track each chess block and see what move has been made by the player. I cant seem to find the exact link on google but i have seen it happen so it is possible. Reply is appreciated.